# postgres query count characters and order by longest length

Tags: postgresql

I'm using the following query to print all title from stories table

```
select title from stories;
```

which show me all titles , 
The point here how to tweak  it and do the following :

```
`order by longest title or even count longest title`
```

any tips

Comment: `select title from stories order by char_length(title) desc`?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

If you to order by the length of the title (longest to shortest) you should use the following query

```
select title from stories order by length(title) desc
```